# Sublime Regex Variable Handling?

Tags: regex, variables, sublimetext2, sublimetext

completely stumped on this one;

trying to recognize this:
x
*content*
end_x

I'm trying to get sublime to recognize for some specific functions for a programming language - for example, I'm trying to get the first bit of the function to be recognized (which could be any string x) then have the full function (including any characters). The only defining feature of the function is the closing statement "end_", followed by the same string x from the opening statement.

I'm just wondering if this is possible? If so, how?

---

I should probably add - I'd really only want to highlight x and end_x, not particularly the content *content*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
(?s)(\S+) .*? end_\1
```

See the sample matches in [the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/40).

**Explanation**

- `(?s)` activates `DOTALL` mode, allowing the dot to match across lines
- The parentheses in `(\S+)` capture any chars that are not white-space chars
- `.*?` lazily matches up to...
- `end_` literal chars
- `\1` the content that was matched by Group 1

Comment: Cheers, very useful - Haven't seen that website before either! Also very good!

Comment: Would there be a way of recognizing only x and end_x without also recognizing all of the content too?

Comment: You mean you only want to match x? Sure, small tweak: we'll match x and look ahead to the rest without matching it. `(?s)(\S+)(?= .*? end_\1)`

Comment: Preferably i'd only want to match x, and end_x

Comment: No worries, I matched it with : (?m)(\S+)(?= .*?(end_\1)) - Thanks for all your help!